# MIPS register never updated

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I'm trying to find the size of my input string in MIPS. (max is 100 characters but I need to know the exact amount the user has input). The string ends when the user inputs a new line. From what I noticed the loop works properly, when it comes to incrementing the iterator and size. However, the `$t7` register which is supposed to store the current character to be compared with `\n` is never updated. It always stays at 0. This is why I am experiencing an infinite loop as the breaking condition is never met.

```
.data

input: .space 400
iterator: .word 0
size: .word 0

.text


main:
#Getting user input 
li $v0,8
la $a0,input
li $a1, 400
syscall 
la $s0, ($a0)
lw $t2, iterator
lw $t6, size 
li $t5, '\n'
jal size_loop

size_loop: 
sll $t4, $t2,0 #t4 = 1 * t2
addu $t4, $t4, $s0 #t4 = t4 + memory loccation of input
lb $t7, ($t4)
beq $t5, $t7, exit_size_loop
addi $t2, $t2,1
addi $t6, $t6,1
j size_loop

exit_size_loop:
addi $s6, $t6, 0
j printing_loop
```

Comment: At least two problems: you are using the address of `newline` not the value and you are comparing words instead of bytes.

Comment: Do I change `lw $t7, ($t4)` to `lb $t7, ($t4)` and how do I load `newline`, when I used `lw` I got an alignment error

Comment: Yes. Also `newline` is a byte, use `lb` there too , or just do `li $t5, '\n'`. You scale `$t4` by `4` too, no idea why.

Comment: I saw in a tutorial that words are stored in 4 bits so that if I want to print them from an array I must jump by 4 every time. The tutorial used full words rather than individual characters tho. Should I just get rid of the `sll $t4, $t2,2` line? I am trying to count the amount of characters in a sentence basically.

Comment: Yes you need to get rid of that, since characters are 1 byte each.

Comment: @Jester I updated the code, can you please confirm this is the right way to proceed? I want to store the size in `$s6` for later usage, this is what the exit_size loop does.